# IE9 ignoring media queries

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, media-queries

This is my first attempt at developing a responsive site. It's working fine in all browsers but IE9. I know that IE9 is compatible with media queries. I checked to see if compatibility mode was turned off and I don't see the icon visible so I believe that it is. My media queries are listed below the base styles. I'll just paste in a few media queries below so that I don't exceed any character limits. Let me know if you need to see more. Note: The doc type is for html5.

**Media Queries:**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
  /* 320 =================================================== */

  header .logo a {
    background:url(../images/logo-320.png) no-repeat;
    width:213px;
    height:69px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:35px;
    display:block;
}

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    header {min-width:100%;}

    .main-link-wrap {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

    .featured-prod {
        width:100%; 
    }

    footer {
        min-width:100%;
}

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  /* 480 =================================================== */

    header .logo a {
    background:url(../images/logo-480.png) no-repeat;
    width:310px;
    height:94px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:5px;
    display:block;
}

.featured-prod .product-box {
    width:185px;    
    margin-left:1.8%;
    margin-right:1.8%;
    text-align:left;
    color:#282828;
    font-size:12px;
    font-size:1.2rem;
    line-height:13px;
    float:left;
}

footer .address {
    font-size:22px;
    line-height:32px;   
}

}
```

Comment: Do you use compatibility mode?

Answer (score 1):

Tested with a very simple html5 page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Referenced your stylesheet.  Added

> body {background: #F00;}

to the first query and

> body {background: #00F;}

to the second query.

Background changes from red to blue as expected when resized in IE9, indicating that media query is working.  I suggest try adding the same to your page to prove the media queries.

If the background changes as expected then there is something else wrong with your CSS (e.g. is it targeting the correct element; is another style overriding etc.)

If the background doesn't change then there is something unusual going on in your page, or with compatibility, etc.

Comment: It turned out to be a compatibility issue after all. I needed to add this strip of code to the header: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> I spent a lot of time on this :/, thinking that wasn't the issue, so I really appreciate the help.

Comment: This is Exactly what is needed to make the responsive activation on IE 9. It worked flawlessly for me. Thank you man, you saved my time!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using a `max-width: 479px` and a `max-width: 480px` media query? 
I assume you're not seeing any of your styling in the `max-width: 479px` block? This is because those rules are being overridden by your `max-width:480px` rule.

Here's why, if a browser is 320px wide - that means it is less than the maximum width of 479px but it is also less than 480px (both conditions are satisfied). And because you've got the `max-width: 480px` block after your `max-width:479px` it's overriding those rules. My suggestion would be for you to include the rules in your `max-width: 480px` in your `max-width: 479px` block or vice-verse.

As an FYI, this problem is not IE9 specific - arranging your CSS rules in that sense will behave the same way across all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I figured out what the problem was. After hunting around some more, I kept going back to the compatibility issue. I found this strip of code that I needed to go in the header. <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> BUT I will make sure those styles are showing up properly bc I didn't realize that could be an issue - thanks!

Comment: I'm new at building responsively - building from scratch rather than using a boilerplate to hopefully get a good understanding of all the roadblocks and finding out what I need to overcome them. Hopefully, keeping the code light in the process! My text feat is to find out how to get IE8 responsive. I'm looking into response.js at the moment.

Comment: ah i see, ye you may also want to make sure ur media query blocks are arranged in the best way to make it responsive the way you want. as for IE8 response.js is probably the ideal solution - you can also look into modernizr to load in css files based on viewport size - both essentially do the same thing.